# custom satellite image as background in ggplot

Tags: image, r, ggplot2

I want to use a satellite image as a background for plotting polygons, points, etc  ... using `ggplot`.

I managed to use google earth imagery with the `ggmap` function but I'd rather have a false colour composite from my own image as a background. As this image is rather heavy (>2GB) I prepared the false colour composite in Arcmap and exported it as .jpeg with coordinates attached (.jgw) to reduce resolution.

The problem is how I can add this image as a (georeferenced base) layer in ggplot? When importing the jpeg (938 rows and 1743 columns) using `readGDAL`, a SpatialGridDataFrame is created with the three (RGB) bands.

All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The core piece to a `ggmap` object is just a matrix of colors with some attributes (use the `str` function on one).

You should be able to read in your jpeg file and create a raster from it, then just change the attributes to match those of a `ggmap` object (mainly just the class and the bounding box information).  You should then be able to use it with the `ggmap` function.

Comment: Thanks. This worked with the image being in latlon. Is there however a possibility to use an image with projected (UTM) coordinates? ggmap fails on this. This would be useful as the original image was delivered in UTM. Consequently, when reprojecting the image, the result is slightly skew creating some no data zones at the borders. This is not a real problem, but it looks nicer when the image is aligned to the axes.

Comment: You might try looking into the different projections available in ggmap: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_map.html